# IIS 6: Getting 401.2 access denied with anonymous authentication enabled

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis-6

I have added a web application to an existing site. The existing site uses basic authentication over https, but the new web application is running in a subfolder where I disabled basic authentication and enabled anonymous authentication (which is disabled for the rest of the site).

So a straight html page works as expected, you can access it without credentials. You can even see it yourself here: https://csssreg.fhcrc.org/physicianSurvey/faq.html

But I placed the new application's aspx page in this folder and I get the 401.2, as you can see here: https://csssreg.fhcrc.org/physicianSurvey/physicianPathologySurvey.aspx

I've been wracking my brain and straining my fingers googling this issue, but nothing solid has turned up. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can allow anonymous access to the aspx page? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the <authentication> and <authorization> elements in web.config set to?

Comment: They look like this:

<authentication mode="Windows" /> 

<authorization>    
        <allow roles="CSS_DMZ\RegTRs,CSS_DMZ\RegSiteAdmins" />
        <deny users="*" />
</authorization>

Comment: Looking more closely at the <authorization> element, I found by adding the below code that anonymous access should be granted, but it doesn't work either: 
`<location path="~/physicianSurvey/physicianPathologySurvey.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>`

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
<authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

Grant access to any **authenticated** user.

To grant anonymous access you need to use

```
<authorization>
      <allow users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there was an error in the global.asax that was causing the page to be redirected to a default error page, and that page was the 401 culprit. Go figure! But thanks to both commenter for at least helping me change my perspective just enough to get the thing.